# Как по нажатию на кнопку создать новое CardView?

Tags: java, android, android-button, cardview

У меня есть CardView в которой 2 кнопки "добавить" и "удалить". При нажатии на кнопку "добавить" я перехожу на новую активити и там страница для создания новой CardView.[image: Само CardView]

Точно такое же CardView Должно создаваться в этой активности по нажатию на кнопку"Create"
Опишите код пожалуйста полностью, спасибо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть пример добавления кнопки, а нужно CardView

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    click = click + 1;
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnCreate:
            // Создание LayoutParams c шириной и высотой по содержимому
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    wrapContent, wrapContent);
            // переменная для хранения значения выравнивания
            // по умолчанию пусть будет LEFT
            int btnGravity = Gravity.CENTER;
            // определяем, какой RadioButton "чекнут" и
            // соответственно заполняем btnGravity
            switch (rgGravity.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
                case R.id.rbLeft:
                    btnGravity = Gravity.LEFT;
                    break;
                case R.id.rbCenter:
                    btnGravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
                    break;
                case R.id.rbRight:
                    btnGravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
                    break;
            }
            // переносим полученное значение выравнивания в LayoutParams
            lParams.gravity = btnGravity;

            // создаем Button, пишем текст и добавляем в LinearLayout
            TextView btnNew = new TextView(this);
            btnNew.setText(etName.getText().toString());
            llMain.addView(btnNew, lParams);
            if (click == 3){
                btnCreate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.btnClear:
            llMain.removeAllViews();
            btnCreate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            click = 0;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Удалено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
```

Comment: ого...какие требования.

Comment: Согласен, но это нужно...

Comment: если вы не напишите минимальный воспроизводимый код (который пытались написать) и который отображает суть того, что у вас не получается, то возможно вам никто и не поможет. Но вы прикрепили 2 скрина и написали что вам надо...почему б не обратится у фрилансерам?

Comment: У меня есть код, добавляющий кнопку, или TextView или любой стандартнй компонент. Но у меня не получается добавить именно CardView

Comment: если на экране можно создавать несколько кард вью, то сделайте ресайклер, где итемами будут эти кард вьюхи, и просто добавляйте в список адаптера новый итем.